# How can I make Filerobot Image Editor component, responsive in React js?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive

*Filerobot Image Editor is an image editor that can be implemented in websites. it supports React, vanilla JS,etc...*

as you can see here from their own website, they have responsive one for themselves:

https://scaleflex.github.io/filerobot-image-editor/

but I couldn't find any documentation about how to make the component responsive.

I don't know if there's specific CSS that needs to be customized or specific prop.

this is my React component:

```
  <FilerobotImageEditor
          source="https://scaleflex.airstore.io/demo/stephen-walker-unsplash.jpg"
          onSave={(editedImageObject, designState) =>
            console.log("saved", editedImageObject, designState)
          }
          onClose={() => {}}
          annotationsCommon={{
            fill: "#ff0000",
          }}
          Text={{ text: "Filerobot..." }}
          Rotate={{ angle: 90, componentType: "slider" }}
          tabsIds={[TABS.ADJUST, TABS.ANNOTATE, TABS.WATERMARK]} // or {['Adjust', 'Annotate', 'Watermark']}
          defaultTabId={TABS.ANNOTATE} // or 'Annotate'
          defaultToolId={TOOLS.TEXT} // or 'Text'
        />
```